# If a set is a dense or relatively dense subset of a topological group

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, topological-groups

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, and $T$ is a topological group which continuously acts on $X$ on the right. We call the pair $(X,T)$ a (right) transformation group.

We know that $(X,\mathbb R)$ is a topological group. Fix $x\in X$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Let $A_x(U)$ be the set of all $t\in \mathbb R$ such that $x.t\in U$. 
We call $x$ an almost periodic point if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a compact set $K_x(U)$ such that $\mathbb R=K_x(U)+A_x(U)$. Is it true that this defining condition requires $A_x(U)$ to be relatively dense?

I solved this already trivial question: 
Let $B$ be an open ball centered at a fixed $t\in \mathbb R$  of radius $\sup \{|x|: x\in K_x(U)\}$. Write $t$ as the sum $a+k$ with $a\in A_x(U), k\in K_x(U)$. then $a\in B$ and $x.a\in U$. That is, $A_x(U)$ is relatively dense.

Comment: I edit the question so it will be clear that $A(U)$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Yes it’s better thanks @Yanko

Comment: @Yanko it means every element in $T$ can be written as the group composition (additive notation) of an element in $K$ and an element in $A$.

Comment: I post an answer. However now I'm a bit confused about the definition of relatively dense for general topological spaces (how do you define that?). Anyway my answer shows that it may not be dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not necessarily dense**

For trivial example:

Let $T$ be any compact group. If $T$ acts trivially, $x\in X$ any point. Then $A_x(U)$ could be empty if $x\not\in U$.

Even if $T$ acts transitively on $X$ the answer is no: For instance take $T$ to be any compact group and $X=T$ (say $X=T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$).

Then for any $x\in X$ and $U\subseteq X$. $A_x(U) = -x+U\subseteq T$. Clearly there exists a compact set $K_x(U)$ such that $T=K_x(U)+A_x(U)$ but $A_x(U)$ is not dense.

Comment: But since the group action $X\times T\rightarrow X$ is continuous, fixing $x\in X$ and $t\in T$ and a neighborhood $S$ of t, for a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $M$ of $t$ such that $N.M$ lies in $U$, hence $N.(M\cap S)$ also lies in $U$, so there is a $t’\in S$ with $x.s\in U$ implying that $t’\in A$, i.e. $A$ is dense.

Comment: @User12239 What's $A$? As far as I understand we have a different set $A$ for every $U$. So this argument won't work.

Comment: I mean that all such $A’s$ are dense, what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: @User12239 Ok let's see what I understand: You fix an open set $U$ and you want to prove that $A_x(U)$ is dense. Now you take a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $M$ of $t$ (what's $t$?) such that $N.M\subseteq U$ - you can't do that for any $t$. Thus, $N.(M\cap S)$ lies in $U$ (where did $S$ comes from?). How does this implies that there is $t'\in S$ with $x+s\in U$? It could be that $M\cap S = \emptyset$.

Comment: The group action map is continuous at every pair $(x,t)$. So there are always such neighborhoods $N,M$ ,fixing such a pair $(x,t)$. Since $S$ was an already fixed neighborhood of $t$, it intersects with $M$.

Comment: Do I need to write this solution in more details or is there no ambiguity in my solution now?

Comment: @User12239 yes please. Add that to your question (also please let me know which definition of "dense subset" you use).

Comment: I was wrong. It is not necessary dense but relatively dense. I wrote my solution in the question box. Also my book was talking about $\mathbb R$, not an arbitrary topological group. By definition, a relatively dense subset of $R$ is a set such that for some $R$, every ball of radius $R$ intersects the set.